# Converting from HashSet<String> to String[]

Tags: java, arrays, hashset

What's the best way to convert `HashSet<String>` to `String[]`?

Comment: Remember a `HashSet` does not have a guaranteed order, so you won't know what order the array will be in.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

```
set.toArray(new String[set.size()]);
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it (+1)

Comment: I would use set.toArray(new String[0]); or even set.toArray(EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY); The set.size() does not add any performance benefit but uses up mental space for the reader.

Comment: It is also possible to do `set.toArray(new String[]{});` in java 12. My IDE, IntelliJ, says "In older Java versions using pre-sized array was recommended, as the reflection call which is necessary to create an array of proper size was quite slow. However since late updates of OpenJDK 6 this call was intrinsified, making the performance of the empty array version the same and sometimes even better, compared to the pre-sized version.  Also passing pre-sized array is dangerous for a concurrent or synchronized collection".

Answer (score 5):

Answer of JB Nizet is correct, but in case you did this to transform to a CSV like string, with Java 8 you can now do:

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
System.out.println(String.join(", ", mySet));

Output is: a, b, c
```

This allows to bypass array notation (the `[]`).

Answer (score 0):

The [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)'s answer is correct. In Java 15, the better answer is:

```
set.toArray(new String[0]);
```