# java.lang.Object[] cannot be converted to java.lang.String[]

Tags: java, arrays, string, hashset

I am new to Java. I have a HashSet of String and I am trying to convert the contains into a String[]. I follow the solution here [Converting from HashSet<String> to String[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474656/converting-from-hashsetstring-to-string)
But still got error. Here is my code:

```
Set set = new HashSet<String>();
// Add elements into set
// ...
String[] words = set.toArray(new String[set.size()]);
```

The error I got is "incompatible types: java.lang.Object[] cannot be converted to java.lang.String[]"

Comment: Why are you not declaring the set initially to be a String Set?: `Set<String>` e.g., `Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();`

Comment: @ZigZagZebra Don't mix raw types and generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the obvious solution: Just make it a generic `Set<String>`.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: can you tell me why casting set.toArray() to (String[]) isn't acceptable I deleted mine that said that because it got downvoted

Comment: @JRowan: the OP is already using generics but incompletely, and if you cast you lose the main reason for using generics -- you lose compile-time type checking. So if you're already using generics, the better answer is to use them correctly, not to cast.